# Requiring a json file in node js the json is updated but the next loop iteration it dosent repull the json it keeps the old version?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, parsing

I have a node js code that requires a json file saves a specific key value pair and the rest of the loop changes the jsons field “version”:”number” value but when the loop hits the second time I don’t get the updated value here us the code-
‘’’
var data = require(“config.json)
var version = data.version
‘’’

Version here equals to 6.3.2

The versions adds up correctly.
But on the next loop iteration the json in the data.version field gets updated to 6.3.3 but this code that runs again:

‘’’
var data = require(“config.json)
var version = data.version
‘’’

Still shows the version 6.3.2
Even though the json file got updated how can i update the version variable to store the correct version which is 6.3.3 like on the file itself

Comment: Format your code properly! Use backticks.

Answer (score 0):

The results of `require` are cached.

If you want to get data from a JSON file that has changed after the JS program has been compiled, use the `fs` module and `JSON.parse` instead of `require`.

Comment: I Tried with fs.readsync and than json.parse and on the next iteration it dosent read the file to :/ maybe i need to make it synchronize?

Comment: If you're using `readSync` then I don't know why it would be asynchronous. You should provide a [mcve] instead of snippets of code.